# Second order central difference of the Nth order

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I'm trying to find some tabulated data in some big-and-smart-book with regards to second order central difference of a function of just one variable: f''(x).

I did find formula for 7th order [1], but I need higher orders, like 12 or 15.

thanks a lot!

[1] http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/numerical-methods/numerical-derivative/central-differences/

Comment: Why would you need high-order? The high-order methods for differences are much more prone to subtractive cancellation. In any event, the formula below the table in your link is a general formula.

Comment: See [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=3RfZOsDAyQsC&pg=PA15) as well.

Comment: I don't have too much of experience, that's why I was asking, so if 7th order is enough, then i will use it ;). thanks! and thanks for the book!

Comment: I'd like to point you to http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jco.2008.05.007 where it is shown that it is possible to get stable behavior of higher order methods if the stepsize is chosen a posteriori.